# Javascript Filereader only allow .log files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, filereader

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application where I can choose a .log File. This happens with a FileReader. But when the explorer opens, all kind of datas are displayed (.png, .jpg, .docx....). So I want, that only the .log Files are displayed.

Here is my code:

```
// Input File (BUTTON)
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

//Get data input from user
input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    $('#fileName').html(input.files[0].name);

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function () {
        const reslt = reader.result;
        readFile(reslt);
    }
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
    document.getElementById('rankings').style.display = 'none';
}, false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question relates more to html than to javascript. You should use the `accept` attribute and list a comma separated extensions accepted.

In your case:

```
<input type="file" accept=".log" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
//Get data input from user
input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
 let kind = $('#fileName').html(input.files[0].name);
    if(kind != undefined && kind.indexOf('.log') > 0) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function () {
            const reslt = reader.result;
            readFile(reslt);
        }
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
        document.getElementById('rankings').style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false)
```

Hop is save you day.